# Possible to format how numeric columns display?

Tags: list, column

I have a numeric column in a list that displays like so:

```
16,090
```

I would like it to display without the comma:

```
16090
```

Can this be done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the only way is to use a calculated column for the display, `=TEXT(Number_Column,"0")`

Edit:
Unless you're using a DVWP and have control over the output, then you can format it how ever you need to in the XSLT markup.

Answer (score 5):

Numeric formats are determined by your locale settings. So, for instance, if you are using locale 1033 (en-us), you'll see numbers displayed with the comma separator by default. You can change your locale settings, but that will change the formatting at the level where you make the change.

Otherwise, a calculated column or a DVWP are ways to go, as Eric mentions. Keep in mind that displaying numbers inconsistently may well add up to a poor UX.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use an Integer field type, rather than a Number field type.

Unfortunately you cannot create an integer field through the browser, but it's pretty easy to do programmatically

Here's a short powershell script that will do the trick

```
$web=get-spweb http://urltosite
$list = $web.Lists["MyListName"]
$list.Fields.Add("MyIntFieldName", [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldType]::Integer, $false)
```

Comment: Thank Lucas.
I tried your way. It is good in display form, but in edit form, it show commas again.
Is there any way ?
thanks

Comment: Good point. You could put some client side inside the edit form to remove the commas when the page loads, but its a kinda messy solution.